# ローカル環境構築で403 Forbidden

Tags: python, python3, windows, anaconda

anaconda3を使って [style2paints](https://github.com/lllyasviel/style2paints) というWebアプリをローカル環境に導入しようとしています。
環境構築後、python server.pyを実行し、

```
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:80/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

serving on 0.0.0.0:80 view at http://127.0.0.1:80
```

と表示されます。しかし、`http://127.0.0.1:80` に移動しても、

```
Error: 403 Forbidden
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1/' caused an error:

Access denied.
```

としか表示されません。

`http://127.0.0.1/` に接続するたびに

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2018:16:03:45 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 705 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2018:16:03:45 +0900] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 716 "http://127.0.0.1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"
```

がターミナルに表示されるので、環境構築自体には成功していると思います。
おそらくローカルサーバーのポートが解放されてないことが原因だと思うのですが、
windows defender firewall で　ポート8000を送受信ともに開放してみたのですが、変化ありません。
環境はwindows10 anaconda3 python3.6 です。
どうかご教授お願いします。

### 追記

コメントありがとうございます。導入しようとしているwebアプリはstyle2paintsというソフトです。

手順は以下の通りです。

1. anacondaでpython3.6の環境を作る。
2. ターミナルを開く。
3. `pip install tensorflow==1.5.0` を実行
4. ```
   pip install paste
   pip install scikit-image
   pip install keras
   pip install bottle
   pip install gevent
   pip install h5py
   pip install opencv-python
   pip install scikit-image
   ```

   を実行。ここまで必要なモジュールのインストール。
5. `git clone github.com/lllyasviel/style2paints.git` で本体ダウンロード。
6. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fWi4wmNj-xr-nCzuWMsN2rcm0249_Aem から必要ファイル全てダウンロード。
7. 6 でダウンロードしたファイルを `C:/Users/(ユーザー名)/style2paints/V3/server` に格納。
8. `cd style2paints/V3/server`、`python server.py` を実行。

Comment: 「ポート8000を送受信ともに開放してみたのですが〜」とありますが、`server.py` の実行ログではポート 80 を listen している様に見えます。質問文を書く際にどちらかを書き間違えられたのでしょうか？

Comment: ポート開放の問題なら403にすらならないので別の問題っぽいですね。Access denied となっているオブジェクト（ファイルやフォルダ）のアクセス権限とか見直してみるといいかもです。あとは、第三者が再現できるようなコード、手順を提示してもらえると詳しい人が回答してくれるかもしれません。

Comment: 素早い返信ありがとうございます！導入しようとしているwebアプリはstyle2paintsというソフトです。

Comment: 手順は
① anacondaでpython3.6の環境を作る。
② ターミナルを開く。
② # pip install tensorflow==1.5.0 を実行
③ # pip install paste
   # pip install scikit-image
   # pip install keras
   # pip install bottle
   # pip install gevent
   # pip install h5py
   # pip install opencv-python
   # pip install scikit-image を実行
　 ここまで必要なモジュールのインストール。
④ # git clone https://github.com/lllyasviel/style2paints.git で本体ダウンロード。
⑤ https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fWi4wmNj-xr-nCzuWMsN2rcm0249_Aem
　 から必要ファイル全てダウンロード。

Comment: ⑥ ⑤でダウンロードしたファイルを
   C:/Users/(ユーザー名)/style2paints/V3/serverに格納。
⑦ # cd style2paints/V3/server
     python server.py  を実行。
です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style2paints`は、なかなか面白いアプリですね。

Windowsの場合は、ディレクトリの区切り文字がPOSIX準拠とは違う関係で、bottle の方で`Access denied`にされています。`server.py`の上部にある次のコードを

```
@route('/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='game/')

@route('/')
def send_static():
    return static_file("index.html", root='game/')
```

次のように修正するとアクセスできるようになります。

```
@route('/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='game')

@route('/')
def send_static():
    return static_file("index.html", root='game')
```

linuxの場合は、1024 未満のポートへのバインディングは、特権ユーザーに限られている場合が多いので、一般ユーザーで`python server.py`を起動するとアクセスが拒否されることがあります。

その場合には、`server.py`の最後に以下のようなコードがありますが、`port=80`を`port=8080`のようにポート番号を1024よりも大きいものにすることです。

```
if multiple_process:
    run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, server='paste')
else:
    run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, server='paste')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
解決法を試してみたのですが、どれもうまくいきませんでした…
① port=80をport=8080 にメモ帳で書き換えましたが、URLが http://127.0.0.1:8000 になるだけで Error: 403 Forbidden。
② anacondaを管理者として実行してみましたが、Error: 403 Forbidden。
③ セキュリティソフトをオフにしてダウンロードしたモデルに差し替えましたが、Error: 403 Forbidden。
でした。

Comment: @user31132 実際に試してみたら、確かに自分の回答ではどれも上手くいきませんでした。Windowsの場合は、ディレクトリ区切り文字が違うことによってbottleの方でAccess denied.にされていたので回答を修正しておきました。